# How to append items of a list to specific columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a list of strings with n items, say:

```
    list1 = ['a','b',..'y','z']
```

Instead of appending the entire list to a dataframe (which creates n columns), I just want to append the first item to the first column, the last item to the last column and everything in between combined into the middle column.

I tried

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
```

but this creates a separate column for each string item, resulting in n columns

I want the output to be a dataframe of 3 columns such as:

```
         0       1        2
  0      a     b+c+d+..   z
```

Please help a noob out!

Answer (score 4):

Well, manually you can do:

```
a, *b, c = list1

df = pd.DataFrame([a, b, c]).T

   0                                                  1  2
0  a  [b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, ...  z
```

Comment: @yatu _There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it._ +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could unpack the list's first value, middle and end separately and construct the dataframe from these:

```
a, *b, c = list1
pd.DataFrame([a, b, c]).T

   0             1  2
0  a  [b, c ... y]  z
```

---

If you want the items in the midde to be joined into a string, you could do:

```
pd.DataFrame([a, ''.join(b), c]).T

   0     1     2
0  a  bcd...y  z
```

---

A clean way to unpack in these cases is using [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), which as in this case, allows you to "catch all" elements in an iterable, depending on which other elements are also assigned separately. In this case `b` will contain all elements between `a` and `c`.